# How to calculate the load time of a xpages

Tags: xpages

Try to store the date in a session scope and make a difference but it don't work at all

```
On click
sessionScope.StarTime=new Date()

On display
var wTime=new Date()
var wDiff=wTime-sessionScope.StartTime
"Temps de chargement " + wDiff + " ms"
```

Thanks

Comment: please add details, what doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "onDisplay" event, so I presume you added the second part of the code into a computed field. For starters you have a typo in your code Sta**rT**ime ws. Sta**rtT**ime. If you did copy & paste to get the code into the question -> there's your problem.

You also want to learn about the XPages lifecycle, so you can measure it better. There is a free [MasterClass](http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-95GFEX) for it. You also want to have a look at the [XPages Toolbox](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/ProjectLookup/XPages%20Toolbox) that allows you profile your application.

Finally: Watch your network speed too and what it does to your app. Firebug or the Google Chrome developer tools help quite a bit. Is is a bit dated (quite some improvements since then), but [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/ddrschiw/ad109) gives more information on performance